# What jar should I include to use javax.persistence package in a hibernate based application?

Tags: java, hibernate, jar

Is it ok to take it from Glassfish project ( glassfish-persistence-api) or may be there is a Hibernate jar?

Comment: +1 -- I ran into the same issue so you've saved me a lot of hassle trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are developing an OSGi system I would recommend you to download the "bundlefied" version from [Springsource Enterprise Bundle Repository](http://www.springsource.com/repository/app/).

Otherwise its ok to use a regular jar-file containing the **javax.persistence** package

Comment: Schildmeijer is right - the complete URL for Java Persistence API 2.0.0 from SpringSource is http://www.springsource.com/repository/app/bundle/version/detail?name=com.springsource.javax.persistence&version=2.0.0

Answer (score 18):

If you are using maven, adding below dependency should work

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I'm using intellij and it tells me that it couldn't find javax.persistence. any ideas?

Answer (score 12):

You can use the **ejb3-persistence.jar** that's bundled with hibernate. This jar only includes the javax.persistence package.

Answer (score 8):

In the latest and greatest Hibernate, I was able to resolve the dependency by including the hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar within lib/jpa directory. I didn't find the ejb-persistence jar in the most recent download.

Answer (score 4):

hibernate.jar and hibernate-entitymanager.jar contains only the packages org.hibernate.*. So you should take it from the Glassfish project.

Answer (score 3):

For JPA 2.1 the javax.persistence package can be found in here:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

See: [hibernate-jpa-2.1-api on Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.hibernate.javax.persistence%22%20AND%20a%3A%22hibernate-jpa-2.1-api%22)
The pattern seems to be to change the artefact name as the JPA version changes. If this continues new versions can be expected to arrive in Maven Central here: [Hibernate JPA versions](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.hibernate.javax.persistence%22)

The above JPA 2.1 APi can be used in conjunction with Hibernate 4.3.7, specifically:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
   <version>4.3.7.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

In general, i agree with above answers that recommend to add maven dependency, but i prefer following solution.

Add a dependency with API classes for full JavaEE profile:

```
<properties>
    <javaee-api.version>7.0</javaee-api.version>
    <hibernate-entitymanager.version>5.1.3.Final</hibernate-entitymanager.version>
</properties>

<depencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>${javaee-api.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Also add dependency with particular JPA provider like antonycc suggested:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate-entitymanager.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Note `<scope>provided</scope>` in API dependency section: this means that corresponding jar will not be exported into artifact's `lib/`, but will be provided by application server. Make sure your application server implements specified version of JavaEE API.