# JPA 2.1/Hibernate 4.3 deprecation warning

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.1

I'm using `JPA 2.1` sample application with `Hibernate 4.3.x` implementation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
                                http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="unit1">

        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>net.roseindia.model.Product</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/common"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="root"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

In `pom.xml` I have the following dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

The sample command line application works normally (t is very simple) but I get the following warning message when I start it.

```
Apr 13, 2014 1:12:43 PM org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence logDeprecation
WARN: HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead.
```

So, Is it the problem my wrong configuration (and can I avoid it?), or it is an issue in Hibernate implementation?

**UPDATED**

Here is the code which I use:

```
import net.roseindia.model.Product;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public class AppTest {

private static final String PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME = "unit1";
private static EntityManagerFactory factory;

public class AppTest {

    private static final String PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME = "unit1";
    private static EntityManagerFactory factory;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
        EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();

        em.getTransaction().begin();

        Product product = new Product();
        product.setProductName("JPA 2.1 Book");
        product.setProductDescription("This is the latest book on JPA 2.1");
        product.setStockQty(100.00);
        product.setPrice(95.99);
        em.persist(product);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();
        factory.close();

    }
}
```

Comment: Show us how you're creating an EntityManagerFactory. Somewhere, you're using the old org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence instead of the new org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider. A simple search into your code should allow you to find it.

Comment: @JBNizet, I updated running class. Is it enough?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Maybe https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HV-863. Or the persistence.xml that is loaded is not actually the one you're showing us.

Comment: No, I provide exactly the same which I'm running.And yes I also found some similar issues (https://community.jboss.org/thread/233644), but not for version `hibernate 4.3.x` So I was thinking something I don't do correct. Anyway thank you very much.

Comment: Are you using Spring? Could be https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11240

Comment: No, @GreyBeardedGeek, This is a command line simple code. Yes I'm going to become agree that this is a bug.

Answer (score 7):

For Spring folks having that issue, here is what's happening: even when Spring guys solved the issue with class **HibernateJpaVendorAdapter**, you actually need to tell to your **JPA EntityManagerFactory** to use this class. I have removed the warning with the following configuration (notice I've specified a bean for *jpaVendorAdapter*):

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="goal-control-unit" />
    <property name="jpaDialect">
        <bean class="cl.antica.goalcontrol.util.ExtendedHibernateJPADialect" />
    </property>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
    </property> 
</bean>
```

I have debugged your code and it seems that deprecated class is loaded automatically by **Persistence** class. This is the actual code of the **createEntityManagerFactory** which is invoked when you call it by passing just the persistence unit name:

```
public static EntityManagerFactory createEntityManagerFactory(String persistenceUnitName, Map properties) {
    EntityManagerFactory emf = null;
    List<PersistenceProvider> providers = getProviders();
    for ( PersistenceProvider provider : providers ) {
        emf = provider.createEntityManagerFactory( persistenceUnitName, properties );
        if ( emf != null ) {
            break;
        }
    }
    if ( emf == null ) {
        throw new PersistenceException( "No Persistence provider for EntityManager named " + persistenceUnitName );
    }
    return emf;
}
```

The **getProviders()** method includes **org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence** by default as the first possible provider (as a fallback solution I guess). What I would do is something like this:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceException;
import javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider;
import javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProviderResolverHolder;

import org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence;

@SuppressWarnings({"deprecation", "rawtypes"})
public class CustomPersistence extends Persistence {

    public static EntityManagerFactory createEntityManagerFactory(String persistenceUnitName) {
        return CustomPersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(persistenceUnitName, null);
    }

    public static EntityManagerFactory createEntityManagerFactory(String persistenceUnitName, Map properties) {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = null;
        List<PersistenceProvider> providers = getProviders();
        PersistenceProvider defaultProvider = null;
        for (PersistenceProvider provider : providers) {
            if (provider instanceof HibernatePersistence) {
                defaultProvider = provider;
                continue;
            }
            emf = provider.createEntityManagerFactory(persistenceUnitName, properties);
            if (emf != null) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (emf == null && defaultProvider != null)
            emf = defaultProvider.createEntityManagerFactory( persistenceUnitName, properties );
        if ( emf == null ) {
            throw new PersistenceException( "No Persistence provider for EntityManager named " + persistenceUnitName );
        }
        return emf;
    }

    protected static List<PersistenceProvider> getProviders() {
        return PersistenceProviderResolverHolder
                .getPersistenceProviderResolver()
                .getPersistenceProviders();
    }

}
```

I have tested that code and it seems to be good enough to solve the issue. In your code, you just need to replace **Persistence** class by this **CustomPersistence**. I hope this helps.

Comment: Shaka, yes usually I use it with spring, but in this case I used only JPA and getting the warning I wanted to be sure that the warning reason is not the my mistake in configuration. Anyway thank you.

Comment: Answer edited. I have figured out the whole sketch. I hope this really helps you.

Comment: See also: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9141 (fixed in 5.0.0 beta1).

Answer (score 1):

By following the advice in the deprecation warning, I have found it possible to overcome this problem with a relatively tidy Spring bean creation of the Entity Manager Factory.

Starting here:

```
WARN: HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead.
```

We can see the path to obtain a class compatible with javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory from the [HibernatePersistenceProvider javadocs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/jpa/HibernatePersistenceProvider.html). First you need an instance of the HibernatePersistenceProvider, then the createEntityManagerFactory method is called. Here is the Spring Bean wiring which avoids the deprecation warning:

```
<bean id="persistenceProvider" class="org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider">
</bean>
<bean id="emf" factory-bean="persistenceProvider" factory-method="createEntityManagerFactory">
   <constructor-arg value="testpersistence"/>
   <constructor-arg><map/></constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

There is a [Stackoverflow thread here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737496/what-jar-should-i-include-to-use-javax-persistence-package-in-a-hibernate-based/27301426#27301426) showing the maven dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to have been filed as a bug in hibernate and is fixed for version 5.0.0.Beta1, see https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9141

At least I had the same problem and changing the dependency to this version made my warnings go away:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0.Beta1</version>
</dependency>
```