# Can't run JavaFX app on another pc

Tags: javafx-2, netbeans-8

I made a JavaFX app and packaged it as a .exe. When I installed it on another pc and tried to run it I get a screen with:> Error invoking method

After that I get a screen with:

> Failed to launch JVM

I added my libraries to the compile & run sections. But probably there is still something wrong with them (not being packaged or something).
When I try to run the jar I get:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.Persistence

Comment: The answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33285108/error-invoking-method-failed-to-launch-jvm/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you bundled the jar containing that class... looking at this [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737496/what-jar-should-i-include-to-use-javax-persistence-package-in-a-hibernate-based) you can get the jar from here: http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/bundle/version/detail?name=com.springsource.javax.persistence&version=2.0.0